# I cant plot values above the tips of bars, XEndPoints dos not work

Tags: matlab, plot

I am using `Matlab 2018b`, I want to plot values above the tips of bars, where

```
A=[4, 8 , 20 ,5];
B=[1,3 4 ,8 ];y
```

I want to write strings above the bars, but when I use `XEndPoints`, the following message is shown :

```
No appropriate method, property, or field 'XEndPoints' for class 'matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.Bar'.
```

my code:

```
function DisplayBarTopsisSawRankReversal(A,B,...  
                                             X1,X2)
    
    max1= max(A(1,:));
    max2=max(B(1,:));
    MAX=max(max1,max2);
    % This will produce 4 groups of 3 different colored bars
    x = [1 2 ];
    
    
    y = [A;B];
    Bar = bar(x,y);  % h will have 3 handles, one for each color of bars
   
    
    set(Bar, {'DisplayName'}, {'Txt1','Txt2'}');

    legend() ;
    
    
    
    somenames={X1,X2};
    set(gca,'xticklabel',somenames);
    ylabel('Rank Reversal Ratio [%]')
    
    ylim([0 MAX+30]);
    
    
    %text(xtips1,ytips1,string( ) ,'HorizontalAlignment','center','VerticalAlignment','bottom')
    opts = {'VerticalAlign','middle', 'HorizontalAlign','left', ...
        'FontSize',8, 'Rotation',90};
    
    text(1, A(1) ,'s' , opts{:});
    numel(Bar)
    
    xtips2 = b(2).XEndPoints;

    end
```

How can I add strings in my case ?

Comment: What is `b`? Did you mean `Bar(2).XEndPoints`?

Comment: @saastn Yes exactly.

Comment: Have you seen this: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/359237-how-do-i-label-each-bar-in-bar-group-with-a-string-on-top

Answer (score 2):

`'XEndPoints'` is a new feature in Matlab R2019b.
This may help you if you try to plot single bar:

```
bar(data);
for i = 1:length(data)
    text(i, data(i), num2str(data(i), '%g'),...
    'HorizontalAlignment','center','VerticalAlignment','bottom');
end
```

When you decide to plot grouped bars, you'd better update your Matlab to R2019b.

There is another way to solve this problem: design your own function "MyBar" using function "rectangle".

Comment: According to the release notes, XEndPoints was added in R2019b. Fixed your post.